# Ring homomorphism from $\mathbb Z$ to $\mathbb Z$ is always identity or $0$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I must assume that there exists f such that:

$$f(x+y) = f(x)+f(y)\\f(x\cdot y) = f(x)\cdot f(y)$$
One thing I managed to do was:

$$f(2+2) = f(2) + f(2) = f(2\cdot 2) = f(2)\cdot f(2) \implies \\f(2)+f(2) = f(2)\cdot f(2)\implies \\2f(2) = f^2(2) \implies f^2(2)-2f(2)=0 \implies f(2)(f(2)-2) = 0 \implies\\ f(2) = 0 \text{ or } f(2) = 2$$

but how to extend this argument to all the integers? That is, how to force $f(3) = 3$ and so on?

Comment: Usually a rinng homomorphism maps $1$ to $1$.

Comment: Many authors would define *ring* as having multiplicative identity, and thus a ring homomorphism from $\mathbb{Z}$ to $\mathbb{Z}$ may well be required to send 1 to 1 (eliminating the trivial map to zero).

Comment: To the commenters above: unless the ring is the zero ring, in which case $0$ is indeed a multiplicative identity (playing a dual role along with being the additive identity).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From $f(1)=f(1\cdot1)=f(1)\cdot f(1)$ we conclude that either $f(1)=1$ or $f(1)=0$. At any rate, $f(n)=f(\underbrace{1+\ldots+1}_n)=\underbrace{f(1)+\ldots +f(1)}_n=nf(1)$, so in the first case $f(n)=n$ and in the second $f(n)=0$ for all $n$ (actually, first only for all $n\ge 0$, but we can take inverses).

Comment: How did you get that bracket underneath to indicate n 1's?

Comment: @SirJective right click equation and select "Show as -> Tex commands"

Comment: Wow I was not aware I could do that. Thank you.

Comment: Worth noting that this proof uses the fact that $\mathbb{Z}$ is generated by 1 to write any n as a sum of 1s.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Use the definition of ring homomorphism i.e. we must have that the multiplicative identity is sent to the multiplicative identity, and that the additive identity is sent to the additive identity.

So if $f(1)=1$, Then $f(n)=f(1+1+1+.....+1) \text{(n times)}=$?